# How to send Gmail email with multiple CC:'s

Tags: python, email-headers

I am looking for a quick example on how to send Gmail emails with multiple CC:'s.  Could anyone suggest an example snippet?

Comment: Show us how do you send with single CC and we will try to help you with making it send more CCs.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is slightly unclear - are you looking to send emails that are CC'd TO multiple Gmail addresses, or are you looking so send e-mails FROM a Gmail address to multiple CCs?

Comment: I want to send the email _TO_ one person, but CC: people.

Comment: @Omnifarious: it only belongs on superuser if the OP is referring to sending email via a local email client. I assume he want to know how to send an email programmatically with multiple CCs, although he doesn't specify. Is that what you're wanting to do @Ethan?

Comment: @Acorn - You're right. I can tell from the responses he's left to some of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rustled up a bit of code for you that shows how to connect to an SMTP server, construct an email (with a couple of addresses in the Cc field), and send it. Hopefully the liberal application of comments will make it easy to understand.

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

## The SMTP server details

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 587
smtp_username = "username"
smtp_password = "password"

## The email details

from_address = "address1@domain.com"
to_address = "address2@domain.com"

cc_addresses = ["address3@domain.com", "address4@domain.com"]

msg_subject = "This is the subject of the email"

msg_body = """
This is some text for the email body.
"""

## Now we make the email

msg = MIMEText(msg_body) # Create a Message object with the body text

# Now add the headers
msg['Subject'] = msg_subject
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address
msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(cc_addresses) # Comma separate multiple addresses

## Now we can connect to the server and send the email

s = SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) # Set up the connection to the SMTP server
try:
    s.set_debuglevel(True) # It's nice to see what's going on

    s.ehlo() # identify ourselves, prompting server for supported features

    # If we can encrypt this session, do it
    if s.has_extn('STARTTLS'):
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo() # re-identify ourselves over TLS connection

    s.login(smtp_username, smtp_password) # Login

    # Send the email. Note we have to give sendmail() the message as a string
    # rather than a message object, so we need to do msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())

finally:
    s.quit() # Close the connection
```

[Here's the code above on pastie.org for easier reading](http://pastie.org/1694055)

Regarding the specific question of multiple Cc addresses, as you can see in the code above, you need to use a comma separated **string** of email addresses, rather than a list.

If you want names as well as addresses you might as well use the [`email.utils.formataddr()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.formataddr) to help get them into the right format:

```
>>> from email.utils import formataddr
>>> addresses = [("John Doe", "john@domain.com"), ("Jane Doe", "jane@domain.com")]
>>> ', '.join([formataddr(address) for address in addresses])
'John Doe <john@domain.com>, Jane Doe <jane@domain.com>'
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: The docs for py 2.7 indicate that `starttls()` isn't needed when using `SMTP_SSL` http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a library, I highly suggest http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/, I have used briefly in the past, and it is very easy to use. You must enable IMAP/POP3 in your gmail account in order to use this.

As for a code snippet (I haven't had a chance to try this, I will edit this if I can):

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

#EDIT THE NEXT TWO LINES
gmail_user = "your_email@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "your_password"

def mail(to, subject, text, attach, cc):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()

   msg['From'] = gmail_user
   msg['To'] = to
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   #THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT IN THE CC EMAILS
   msg['Cc'] = cc
   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
   part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
   Encoders.encode_base64(part)
   part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
           'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
   msg.attach(part)

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
   mailServer.close()

mail("some.person@some.address.com",
   "Hello from python!",
   "This is a email sent with python")
```

For the snippet I modified [this](http://kutuma.blogspot.com/2007/08/sending-emails-via-gmail-with-python.html)

Comment: This is not working for me:

msg['Cc'] = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com']

Comment: **DON'T** use libgmail. It works by scraping the web interface and is depreciated now that gmail has IMAP and SMTP.